# Template Jquery não funciona em pagina HTTPS

Tags: jquery, ajax, template, https

Tenho uma função AJAX que funciona em varias paginas, exceto em uma pagina que utiliza HTTPS:

```
$.ajax({
    url : url,
    type : "get",
    async: false,
    success : function(result) {

       console.log("Status AJAX: " + result.resultStatus);
       if(result.resultStatus == 'SUCCESS'){
           $('#div-select-filter-ligth-box').html(
               $('#select-ligth-box-template').tmpl({
                   lista : result.list
                })
           );
       }
       return false;
    },
    error: function() {
       console.log('AJAX Error');
    }
 });
```

Já debuguei a função e os AJAX esta retornado dados.
Alguem sabe a causa desse problema?

Answer (score 0):

Tente adicionar Access-Control-Allow-Origin ao header do servidor.

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://www.minhapagina.com
```

Caso você esteja utilizando o Google Chrome adicione a extensão Cors ao browser:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon

Answer (score 0):

O fato é que HTTP e HTTPS não conversam entre si (sua descrição tem esse sintoma). Se a resposta vem limpa e a conexão é criptografada o server não vai compreendê-la. Verifique a configuração do seu servidor e se certifique que o JavaScript tem capacidade de trabalhar em HTTPS.